# chartjs-plugin-dragdata isn''t working with scatter charts

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Its seems [chartjs-plugin-dragdata plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-dragdata) is only for linecharts. But in my case I need a scatter chart with one Datapoint which I want to make dragable. But after dragging and dropping the data point it just disappear, also the callback functions onDragStart etc. aren't called. 
So is there an easy way to modify the plugin? Or maybe there is another plugin out there which is doing what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. Just had to add 2 or 3 lines. Here are the two methods which I modified:

```
    function getElement(chartInstance, callback) {
    return function () {
        if (_d3Selection.event) {
            var e = _d3Selection.event.sourceEvent;
            element = chartInstance.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];

            if (element) {
                scale = element['_yScale'].id;
                scaleX = element['_xScale'].id;
                if (typeof callback === 'function' && element) callback(e, element);
            }
        }
    };
}

function updateData(chartInstance, callback) {
    return function () {
        if (element && _d3Selection.event) {
            var e = _d3Selection.event.sourceEvent;
            var datasetIndex = element['_datasetIndex'];
            var index = element['_index'];

            var value = chartInstance.scales[scale].getValueForPixel(e.clientY - chartInstance.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);
            var valueX = chartInstance.scales[scaleX].getValueForPixel(e.clientX-chartInstance.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left );

            chartInstance.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[index] = {x:valueX, y:value};
            chartInstance.update(0);
            if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(e, datasetIndex, index, value);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post this in 2024 with Chartjs updated to v4.4.1, because the `dragdata` still doesn't seem to work with scatter yet.

If you have control over your data, just use `type: 'line'` and `showLine: 'false'` which hides the lines between and makes it look like scatter.